# Best approach to extending contact entity for different audiences

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I am customizing Dynamics CRM 2016 for multiple departments to store contacts. I need to extend the contact entity but I only want to show the department-specific fields to the users of that department.

I can implement field-level-security but that displays all the custom fields (but doesn't allow other departments to see the actual values). That creates a lot of visual pollution.

Is there a better approach to achieve this?

[image: contact entity diagram]

Answer (score 2):

Either create a separate CRM form for each department then control with security role, Or create individual tab/section in single form to show/hide in JavaScript based on dept/user security role.

Comment: Yep, forms controlled by security role were made for this requirement.